# Dynamically changing the value of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So right now I have 'champion' inputs after remove anchor and for some reason I am unable to target it through Jquery in any way. The code below are most important bits.

Here is also working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x97uLkhp/

```
championNumberArray = 0;
championNumber = 1;
 $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){
            $('div#ChampionInput').append(
            '<div class="Champion" data-id="'+championNumberArray+'">\
                 <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
                 <br>\
                 <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
                 <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
                 <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
                 <a href="#" class="AddGeneralChange">Add General Change</a>\
                 <div class="GeneralChanges">\
                 </div>\
                 <div class="SpellChanges">\
                 </div>\
                 <br>\
             <div>');
            for(var key in champions){
                if(champions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    $('#champions').append('<option value="' + key + '">');
                }
            }
            championNumberArray++;
            championNumber++;
        });
        $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove',function(){
            var champion = $(this).closest('.Champion');
            var id = champion.data("id");
            var nextChampion = champion;

            while((nextChampion = nextChampion.next()).length != 0){
                $(this).siblings('ChampionInput').attr('placeholder', 'test');
                nextChampion.attr("data-id",id++);


            }
            championNumberArray=id;
            champion.remove();


        });
```

UPDATE: I am trying to target placeholder which I can't for some reason here is the line I'm trying to execute

```
$(this).siblings('ChampionInput').attr('placeholder', 'test');
```

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for help with here?

Comment: Okay, and what is it that you are trying to achieve there? It looks like you are only incrementing the id on the next instance, which works fine in the fiddle?

Comment: Trying to fix placeholder numbers after removing a champion

Comment: What do you mean by fix them? As in they are breaking, or set them to a fixed number?

Comment: add champions they will be numbered champion 1 2 3 4 5 etc then delete 3rd one they will be numbered now like 1 2 4 5 instead of 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

You can't target an element you have removed since it no longer exists. You have to re-create it to be able to target it again.

As a side note, you can target an element you have hidden.

Comment: $(this).siblings('ChampionInput').next().attr('placeholder', 'test'); I would like to target the next championInput and im using this before removing